# Greenshot unresponsive

Tags: windows, screenshot, unresponsive, greenshot

Starting around this day today I notice Greenshot screenshots getting unresponsive.

It was working very well for many months. I don't think it has updated for all these time. I am using the latest version 1.2.10.6. My Windows also hasn't updated.

When I try to make a screenshot e.g. of a window, of the entire screen, or of a selection by clicking and dragging the mouse, it may decide to hang for few seconds to a minute. At this point when I click on the Greenshot icon in the Windows System Tray, it takes maybe several seconds before it actually opens.

On my docked HP Laptop Windows 7 Professional Computer, Windows Task Manager doesn't show any computationally intensive process.

Before this happened, Greenshot was able to take screenshots very well even at high CPU usage by other applications.

I don't have MS OneDrive or Dropbox installed so they are not interfering.

I followed the Greenshot advice to change the shortcut keys for the screen captures.

It seemed to work at first but then decides to lag again. There are many several seconds delay before the screen is captured.

After restart of my PC, Greenshot sometimes captures immediately upon my key press. Greenshot sometimes lags several seconds before it captures the screen, which by that time could be showing something different.

Greenshot was working perfectly well for several months so I am puzzled what could be the cause of this problem.

Comment: I've recently started to experience this issue myself.  No idea what I did to cause it or how to fix it.

Comment: @Developer i could never solve this but i created a workaround by changing the keystrokes for taking a screenshot ; i decided to go with the macOS style of keyboard shortcuts.